# jquery toggle depending on value of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This must be very simple, but I just got stuck with this... I have a list of products with an input field for the quantity and next to it a column with the prices. The prices are displaying two values. One of them is hidden. If the value of the input field goes over a certain value, it should hide the other price.
Example:
(input: [], show price1price2 )

```
input: [2], show <span class=one>price1</span>
input: [5], show <span class=one>price1</span>
input: [8], show <span class=two>price2</span>
input: [9], show <span class=two>price2</span>
```

My code so far (example, since I show just 2 products):

```
<form name="formname" action="formaction" method="post">
prod 1<input type="text" value="" class="class1" size="3"><span class="one">$1.00</span><span class="two">$2.00</span>
prod 2<input type="text" value="" class="class1" size="3"><span class="one">$4.00</span><span class="two">$6.00</span>
</form>
```

And at the bottom in script tags:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('input.class1').val() > 5) {
       $('.one').show();
       $('.two').hide();
    }
});
```

What am I missing? The form name perhaps?
This is just the first part...

My other question would be.. how can I make it so that if the sum of all the input fields (with class1 as class) is more than 5, do the same. (So now depending on the sum of the input fields, rather than each individual one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputs = $('input[class^=class]');  // get inputs which class name 
                                        // start with "class" eg: class1, class2..

// fire blur event
// you may use keyup or something else

inputs.on('blur', function(e) {
    var val = 0;

    // adding all inputs value
    // of all inputs with class = blured input class

    $('input.' + this.className).each(function() {
      val += parseInt( this.value, 10);        
    });

    // checking for condition
    if (val > 5) {
       $(this).next('.one').show().next('.two').hide();
    } else {
       $(this).next('.one').hide().next('.two').show();
    }
});
```

***[Demo with blur](http://jsfiddle.net/YMSEn/2/)***

***[Demo with keyup](http://jsfiddle.net/YMSEn/3/)***

#### Note

Place you all jQuery codes within `$(document).ready()`.

#### According to comment

***[See this update](http://jsfiddle.net/YMSEn/5/)***

***Code***

```
if (val > 5) {
   $('.one').show();
   $('.two').hide();
} else {
   $('.one').hide();
   $('.two').show();
}
```

***[Update after last comment](http://jsfiddle.net/YMSEn/6/)***

Just change

```
val += parseInt( this.value, 10);
```

to

```
val += parseInt( this.value || 0, 10); // default 0, if no value given
```

#### According to comment

*How to implement above code for select box?*

```
var selects = $('select[class^=class]');  // get selects which class name
                            // start with "class" eg: class1, class2..

// fire change event

selects.on('change', function(e) {
    var val = 0;

    // adding all selects value

    $('select.' + this.className).each(function() {
      val += parseInt( this.value, 10);        
    });

    // checking for condition
    if (val > 5) {
       $(this).next('.one').show().next('.two').hide();
    } else {
       $(this).next('.one').hide().next('.two').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples.. however, I had some issues with the keyup one. If I put 1 in the first and 1 in the second, they behave fine. THen say 4 in the first and 4 in the second, it'll update the second one, not the first. The first would only change if I had both say 1 and then change it to two.. very strange. Other than that, I would like it to update both prices (of prod1 and prod2) if the sum is more than 5...

Comment: Just did that.. EXCELLENT! Thank you!!

Comment: ...however... I still am having issues. If I fill in the first one anything more than 5, it doesn't do anything UNTIL I fill in the next box.. Is there a way around this? (so it'll add everything except for the fields that are empty)

Comment: Now how would this work with a select box instead of textbox?

Comment: @Malachi in case of select box you need to use `change` event.

Comment: Would you be able to show this in a demo? (I assume you use the change instead of the inputs.on?)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it! I was so close and it just never worked. I must have forgotten something tiny.. ugh! Anyway, it works perfectly, thanks a LOT!

Comment: I tried to give another upvote, which resulted in an unupvote. I did another upvote to put it back where it was.. Sorry for the inconvenience. If there is any other way I can increase a vote for you, please let me know!

Comment: @Malachi I've edited my post with solution for select box and now you can upvote it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this on page load, you need to run it each time the value of the input fields is changed.

Consider wrapping your if block in this:

```
$('input.class1').blur(function() {
  if($('input.class1').val() > 5) {
     $('.one').show();
     $('.two').hide();
  }
});
```

Or something to that effect, consider using `$.on()`.

If you want to sum them, assign each input a common class, and use `$.each()`:

```
$('.common-class').each(function() {
  sum = sum + $(this).val()
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may be best suited to add a common class to all input elements you want to track, and then use `$('.common-class').blur(function() { ... });`